# mvc.net custom [Authorize] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with mvc4 in my project, with SimpleMembership role provider. I need to implement task based access in my project. My ActionResult([HttpPost]) consist of Create,Get,Update and Delete methods. I implemented custom Authorize class which is...

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    // Custom property
    public string AccessLevel { get; set; }          
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);


   if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string privilegeLevels = string.Join("", objManager.GetPermissions()); // Call another method to get rights of the user from DB(view,delete,update,create)


        if (privilegeLevels.Contains(this.AccessLevel))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //some code for redirect to request page and showing alert("you don't have permission to do this action") through Response.

    }
}
```

I can't use [AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="Get or Delete or View or Create")] on each ActionResult.
Because I implemented total view, create, update and delete functionality in one ActionResult(which calls methods for create, update, delete and view).

My problem is when i am giving [AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="Get")] for Get methods, [AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="Create")] for Create methods and so on....
After control coming inside ActionResult() it is checking first [AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="some access level")], once it is Authorize, it is not checking for other method [AuthorizeUser].

After trying [AuthorizeUser] on ActionResult(), i came to conclude that only for each page request it is checking for Authorization(not for seconed time), is there any way to call [AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel="some access level")] for more than one time in a single page request.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you annotattig only the Controller? Is this? You should be more clear. Authorization pop's from every request.

Comment: I am not annotating to controller. I am annotating to every method of my ActionResult();